# UNC-linked data in Access MDB is read-only

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 front-end ACCDB.
It has a link to data in an older MDB, on a networked drive, via a UNC link.
The data appears to be read-only when viewed via the front end.
The data has no password; the front end has the UNC location as a trusted location.

What else needs doing, to enable write-access to the data?

Comment: Check your user's permissions for the  file share.  Can your Access user create, modify, and delete a text file in that shared folder?  Also make sure Access recognizes a primary key in the linked table.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but in addition to the trusted locations there is a "allow trusted locations on the network" checkbox that needs to be checked.